# JavaScript loop mixing div

Tags: javascript, html, google-feed-api

it's my first post in here so big hi to all. I’m new to JavaScript and this is what I’m struggling with. Probably the title of my question is a bit ridicules but what I'm working on is a Google Api feed.  The code puts all titles into one div and content into the other. I would like to see them mixed. Please have a look and thank you in advance.

```
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("feeds", "1");

    function initialize() {
      var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://encompassme.com/rss/posts/en.xml");
      feed.setNumEntries(2);
      feed.load(function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {


        var containerTitle = document.getElementById("title");
        var containerContent = document.getElementById("content");

          for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
            var entry = result.feed.entries[i];

            var div = document.createElement("div");
            var diva = document.createElement("div");

            div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title)); 
            diva.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.content)); 


            containerTitle.appendChild(div);
            containerContent.appendChild(diva);

          }

        }
      });
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="entry">
    <div id="title"></div>
    <div id="content"></div> 
   </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

What I'm getting:

```
title
title
content
content
```

What I want:

```
title
content
title
content
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append both the title and div elements to the same container, like this:

```
containerContent.appendChild(div);
containerContent.appendChild(diva);
```

**[Working example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4fBdb/1/)**

The problem was that you were appending all titles to a div, and all content to a other div.

What was happening was this:

First, you added title & content `1`:

```
<div> <!-- Fist div here -->
    Title 1
</div>
<div> <!-- Second div -->
    Content 1
</div>
```

All seems ok, but when you add another article, this is what happened:

```
<div> <!-- Fist div here -->
    Title 1
    Title 2
</div>
<div> <!-- Second div -->
    Content 1
    Content 2
</div>
```

And if you just append the elements in one `<div>`, they will be in there in the order you add them, so resulting in:

```
<div> <!-- Fist div here -->
    Title 1
    Content 1
    Title 2
    Content 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this seems to be an ordering problem is all, you have:

```
      for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[i];

        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var diva = document.createElement("div");

        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));    //this places node after div
        diva.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.content)); //this places node after diva


        containerTitle.appendChild(div); // append after containerTitle
        containerContent.appendChild(diva); //append after containerContent

      }
```

append both after containerContent:

```
        containerContent.appendChild.appendChild(div); // append after containerTitle
        containerContent.appendChild(diva); //append after containerContent
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following

```
 <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        google.load("feeds", "1");

        function initialize() {
          var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://encompassme.com/rss/posts/en.xml");
          feed.setNumEntries(2);
          feed.load(function(result) {
            if (!result.error) {

             var mastercontainer=document.getElementById("master");
          //  var containerTitle = document.getElementById("title");
           // var containerContent = document.getElementById("content");

              for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
                var entry = result.feed.entries[i];

                var div = document.createElement("div");
                var diva = document.createElement("div");

                div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title)); 
                diva.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.content)); 


                mastercontainer.appendChild(div);
                mastercontainer.appendChild(diva);

              }

            }
          });
        }
        google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

        </script>
      </head>

  <body>
  <div id="entry">
    <div id="master"></div>

   </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When posting answers, I'd suggest explaining what's different in the answer, and why the answer works. Other than that, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank you, I’m literally blown away how helpful you guys are !